# Zpool import - one or more devices is currently unavailable

Tags: zfs

When attempting to import a zpool with -m (also -F and -f and combinations thereof), I receive: "cannot import 'tank2': one or more devices is currently unavailable"

I believe the missing devices (below) were a log and a cache vdev.  The mirrored log device files are available and for other pools that did not have an additional vdev missing, an import with -m worked.

Is there a way to recover/import?

sudo zdb -e tank2 results in:

```
Configuration for import:
        vdev_children: 3
        version: 5000
        pool_guid: 11600171545368744222
        name: 'tank2'
        state: 0
        hostid: 2831219715
        hostname: 'st1'
        vdev_tree:
            type: 'root'
            id: 0
            guid: 11600171545368744222
            children[0]:
                type: 'mirror'
                id: 0
                guid: 9447464883398653648
                metaslab_array: 256
                metaslab_shift: 37
                ashift: 12
                asize: 16000885456896
                is_log: 0
                create_txg: 4
                children[0]:
                    type: 'disk'
                    id: 0
                    guid: 3886967508015062789
                    whole_disk: 1
                    DTL: 120
                    create_txg: 4
                    path: '/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000c500c522d118-part1'
                children[1]:
                    type: 'disk'
                    id: 1
                    guid: 15212288139380056264
                    whole_disk: 1
                    DTL: 119
                    create_txg: 4
                    path: '/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000c500c523813a-part1'
            children[1]:
                type: 'missing'
                id: 1
                guid: 0
            children[2]:
                type: 'missing'
                id: 2
                guid: 0
        rewind-policy:
            rewind-request-txg: 18446744073709551615
            rewind-request: 2
zdb: can't open 'tank2': No such device or address
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works. Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of your question. Then take a look to [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see if some _on-topic questions_ are already asked.